# openNi, openCV, Processing: kinect with Java

Tags: java, opencv, kinect, processing, openni

I did a digital art project in Java, my teachers liked it and want me to make a museum exhibition of it, they lend me a Kinect without teaching me how to use it with Java..
I fund nothing really comprehensive about it on internet, so i need to know What are the steps to follow to use the kinect with Java to capture positions.

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Have you considered checking this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575667/how-can-i-access-the-kinect-using-java

Answer (score 0):

Have you already looked at into the samples that came with [openKinect](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page) to get the basics of it? I would suggest you to do the same with [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).